# Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter? Bean property 'engine' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, dependencies, javabeans

I have two POJO class and i use dependency injection two initialized value but I got an error? When i run my CarAndEngine Class i got an Error.

**Error :- WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'c' defined in class path resource [car.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'engine' of bean class [com.meet.SpringExample.Car]: Bean property 'engine' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?**

Car.java

```
package com.meet.SpringExample;

public class Car {
private String carname;
private Engine engine;

public Car() {
    System.out.println("car");
}
public String getCarname() {
    return carname;
}
public void setCarname(String carname) {
    this.carname = carname;
}

public void printCarData() {
    System.out.println("carname"+carname);
    System.out.println("ModelYear"+engine.getModelYear());
}
}
```

Engine.java

```
package com.meet.SpringExample;

public class Engine {
private String modelYear;


public Engine() {
    System.out.println("Engine");
}

public String getModelYear() {
    return modelYear;
}

public void setModelYear(String modelYear) {
    this.modelYear = modelYear;
}

}
```

car.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="c" class="com.meet.SpringExample.Car">
        <property name="carname" value="Ferrari"></property>
        <property name="engine" ref="e"></property>

    </bean>
</beans>
```

engine.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="e" class="com.meet.SpringExample.Engine">
        <property name="modelYear" value="2015"></property> 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

CarAndEngine.java

```
package com.meet.SpringExample;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class CarAndEngine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String file[]=new String[] {"car.xml","engine.xml"};
        ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(file);
        Car c=(Car)context.getBean("c");
        c.printCarData();
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no setter method for the `engine` property of `Car`.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand.  Can you tell me what I do Now?

Comment: On solution is to add a `setEngine` method to `Car`.

Comment: Thanks, Brother. code in working now